# RibbonPageGroup throws exception when RibbonControl expands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I use DevExpress **RibbonControl** on VS2010 WPF C# project.

I found if `RibbonPageGroup` in the RibbonControl has `IsVisible=false`, when RibbonControl click expand after minimize, application crash and throw `"NullReferenceException was unhandled"` exception.

I tried setting **IsVisible** to **false** in XAML, and also in code behind (i.e. turn IsVisible to false during run-time), both produce the same exception. I tried:

- used `try{}..catch{}`, but cannot catch any exception
- had made sure there're no assembly version conflicts: use only v11.1 DevExpress assemblies
- clean -> rebuild -> close VS2010 -> open and rebuild again etc.: still same exception
- If I change `IsVisible=false` to `IsEnable=false` instead, then applications runs fine, no exception. Very wierd..

Have someone encounter this problem? Setting Visibility on RibbonControl's `RibbonPageGroup` should be very common (e.g. switching between user and administrator mode). Is it a bug or is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described is a bug. For this reason, the bug report you posted on this subject ([B207506](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B207506.aspx)) and then closed has been reactivated. As far as I can see, the [hot fix is already available](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/archive/2008/07/10/getting-your-fix-the-devexpress-way.aspx).

P.S. Please use the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/support/center) to ask a questions or report issues, because there is no guarantee of DX involvement when you use the communities, newsgroups or other communication channels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with DevExpress controls, but in WPF IsVisible should be read-only and affected by the Visibility property. You are not supposed to set IsVisible.

Try setting `Visibility="Collapsed"` instead.

Comment: In DevExpress, IsVisible has only True or False. I'm also trying to figure out how to "hide" the control instead..anyway thanks for your input,